# Seurat analysis only with matrix with no barcode and features

Tags: seurat, single-cell

I have downloaded a dataset from GEO and only the matrix (mx) files are available. How can I perform the analysis without the barcode and the gene features?

Comment: what do you mean by gene features? Does the matrix have genes as rownames? Can you share the GEO number? you need gene names or metadata ...

Comment: Seurat has different functions that can read different types of data. Please share a few rows and columns of your data and we can try to point you to the right direction (function).